# Examples of cross-platform style guides

Tags: style-guide

Would someone know good examples of cross-platform style guides?

I am working on structuring style/design guide to be used across 5+ platforms

Answer (score 3):

Google has a wonderful visual style guide that applies across platforms:

https://www.behance.net/gallery/Google-Visual-Assets-Guidelines-Part-1/9028077
https://www.behance.net/gallery/9084309/Google-Visual-Assets-Guidelines-Part-2

Here's a [style guide for an IBM conference](ftp://service.boulder.ibm.com/software/cn/downloads/Impact2010_StyleGuide_011210.pdf), although it's more concerned with branding than software, it could serve as the basis of a software visual style guide.